# change background image if I checked an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, append

I have several divs from append results, inside the div contains the image and radio button, if I choose one div how do I change the image

```
$("#baggageAirline").append('<div class="col-3 list-baggage");"><input type="radio" class="input-radio-costum" required onchange="changeBackground('+response[i].airlines_id+' value="'+response[i].airlines_id+'")" onclick="getPrice('+response[i].price_in_SGD+')" name="baggage" value="'+response[i].baggage.max_range+' '+category+'"><img src="{{asset("assets/image/baggage.png")}}" alt="" class="image-selected'+response[i].airlines_id+'" width="80px"><p class="baggage-amount">'+response[i].baggage.max_range+' '+category+'</p><p class="text-center tcc">'+response[i].currency_symbol+' '+response[i].price_in_SGD+'</p></div>');
```

I have tried entering the ID into the onchange event, but the id is undefined

```
function changeBackground(id){
   alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'a'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'b'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'c'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'd'
}];

$('#append').click(function() {
  $.each(data, function(i, v) {
    $("#baggageAirline").append('<div class="col-3 list-baggage" id=' + v.id + '><input type="radio" name="baggage" class="input-radio-costum" required onchange="changeBackground(' + v.id + ')">' + v.name + '</input></div>');
  });
  $('#append').hide();
});

function changeBackground(id) {
  $('.list-baggage').css('background-image', 'none');
  $('#' + id).css('background-image', "url('https://picsum.photos/id/264/100/100')");
}
```

```css
.list-baggage {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='baggageAirline'>
</div>

<button id='append'>Append</button>
```

Comment: book-baggage:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: changeBackground is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (book-baggage:1)

Comment: yes you are right, I was wrong to enter a function thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**Change Dynamic Background**

```js
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function(){

  var backgroundImg=["https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
                    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/556416/pexels-photo-556416.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
                    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
                    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/592077/pexels-photo-592077.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
                    ]

    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
    
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backgroundImg[i]+"')";

}
```

```html
<h1>Change Dynamic Background</h1>
<div></div>
<button id="demo"> CHange Image</button>
```